# PHP UML Class diagrams plugin for eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, class, uml, plugins

I've searched but the questions so far seem to be Java/C# orientated. I was wondering if there was a class diagram GUI for eclipse - or it could be standalone - that better describe PHP classes?

It seems that the ones i've used so far assume you are writing for Java or C#.

Cheers for any pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StarUML has a PHP5 code generator template.

http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/templates.php

Comment: Seems to work! not sure I like the PHP 5 template, but I'm sure I could edit it.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah, that's the nice thing about StarUML, you can easily modify it to fit your needs (and make it export to any language you would like) :p.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest using argouml or bouml. both are open source. it seems like staruml has no active development.